# Can I use one 8GB RAM module in place of two 4GB modules?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I have a MacBook Pro 13-inch, Mid 2012 and one of its RAM slots appears to have been damaged (The computer restarts when moved too much). So I can only have one RAM module in it. I was reading on Apple's website for changing RAM: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201165#1.
They state that my computer is only able to have a maximum of 8GB RAM.

My question is, can I have a single RAM module with 8GB instead of 2x 4GB RAM modules as they mention on the website?

Comment: I had the same issue once. Re-adjusting the RAM in its slot and blowing some air into it, solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For the **MacBook Pro** 13-inch, Mid 2012, **Apple** only officially supports 8 GB RAM, 2 - 204-pin PC3-12800 (1600 MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM; however, it can actually support 16 GB. So in theory you should be able to use a single 8 GB PC3-12800 (1600 MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM.

You can purchase a single [Crucial 8GB Single DDR3/DDR3L 1600 MT/s (PC3-12800) SODIMM 204-Pin Memory For Mac - CT8G3S160BM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008LTBLLY)  from **Amazon**, currently $48.17 USD.

Or:

[OWC Memory 8.0GB PC12800 DDR3L Module](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/1600DDR3S8GB/), currently $45.99 USD.

[Crucial 8GB DDR3L-1600 SODIMM Memory for Mac](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/macbook-pro-%2813-inch-and-15-inch%2C-mid-2012%29/CT3373653) from Crucial, currently $49.99 USD.

Have a look at the iFixit [MacBook Pro 13" Unibody Mid 2012 RAM Replacement Guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+RAM+Replacement/10374).

Comment: @David Anderson, Thanks, I've update the answer with your links.